# update columns in magento order payment table

Tags: magento

I'm still getting acquainting with magento models.

We have a magento plugin that offer another checkout option.  One of our clients extracts orders and sends the file to their fulfillment center for processing.

This script only extracts order that were processed using cybersource; it checks columns 'cybersource_token' and 'method' in `sales_flat_order_payment`.

Since we are not allowed to update this script I need to set these two columns so orders processed by our checkout plugin are written to the extract file when this script is run.  I'll do this in our plugin after the magento order is created.

I tried the following

```
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment', $order)->getPayment();
$orderPayment->setData('cybersource_token', '1234');
$orderPayment->setData('method', 'cybersource_soap');
```

But can't get this to work.

Any suggestions on how to update these two columns?

Comment: First you should log to $orderPayment like that Mage::log($orderPayment, null, 'orderpayment.log'). Then, you will see log file under youmagnetofolder/var/log. Finally, find cybersource_token in log. let me know result

Comment: Thiha, thanks for your help. here's the code 1. $orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment', $order)->getPayment(); 2.  Mage::log($orderPayment, null, 'orderpayment.log');
log result: "2013-06-22T22:38:33+00:00 DEBUG (7):"

Comment: So you didn't see any record in this log file?

Comment: No :-(.  I wonder if no row is entered until after a specific event happens. Although I'm retrieving the payment after the invoice is  created so I would have thought the payment would be there.

Answer (score 0):

How to do this? Try one option. First one is not pretty sure. Let me know any result.

```
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment');
$orderPayment->setData('cybersource_token', '1234');
$orderPayment->setData('method', 'cybersource_soap');
```

or

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order'); //this line is sample change your $order in here
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
->setCybersource_token('1234')
->setMethod('cybersource_soap');
$order->setPayment($orderPayment);
```

Comment: Thanks Thiha!!!  So far it looks like that worked! I'm going to do more tests.  Questions, if you don't mind; 1) how did u find setCybersource_token and setMethod? and 2) how did you know to do setPayment on the order object?  Thanks again!!!

Comment: 1) I assume, you already add new custom attribute 'cybersource_token' and method is already included. 2) see this link for 2 answer in line 77 to 83

Comment: Thiha, so its partially works.  Its updating the payment table with the new cybersource_token and method but its creating a new order and then subsequently deleting the order.  I suspect I'm not snycning the original order with the payment row I'm updating

Comment: Thiha, got it!! This did the trick - $originalOrder->getPayment()
->setCybersourceToken($result->TransactionIdentifier)->setMethod('your method'); Thanks again for your help!